# Visualise normals of PointNormal point cloud in PCL

Tags: c++, exception, new-operator, point-cloud-library

I am trying to visualize normals that are contained in a `pcl::PointNormal` point cloud. I try to do this with following code:

```
std::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer;
std::mutex viewerMutex;

void viewerThreadFunction() {
    while(true) {
        if(viewer->wasStopped()) break;
        viewerMutex.lock();
        viewer->spinOnce();
        viewerMutex.unlock();
    }
}

int main() {
    viewer = std::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer>(
                    new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("Viewer"));
    viewer->setBackgroundColor(0, 0, 0);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>);

    viewer->addPointCloudNormals<pcl::PointNormal, pcl::PointNormal> (cloud, cloud, 25, 0.15, "normals"); // It throws an exception here:

    std::thread viewerThread{viewerThreadFunction};

    while(true) {
        // populate the point cloud
        viewerMutex.lock();
        viewer->removePointCloud("normals");
        viewer->addPointCloudNormals<pcl::PointNormal, pcl::PointNormal> (cloud, cloud, 25, 0.15, "normals");
        viewerMutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

I get an exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'
    what(): std::bad_array_new_length
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried to rewrite the program so, that `viewer->addPointCloudNormals` is called only on a populated point cloud, but it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your viewer might be missing the actual point cloud data.

try adding

```
viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>(cloud, "foo", 1);
```

before calling addpointcloudnormals

Comment: Ah, and you are passing an empty cloud to the viewer. Your code works (visualization is bad but it's working) for me if I add a cloud with data.

Comment: the viewer was missing the points. The cloud object existed, so it was not a null pointer, but it did not contain any points. I had to add an if statement to check it. Why is visualization bad?

Comment: I realized afterwards that it was bad just because of my data was in millimeters, so the line it drew was minimal and flickered. Changing the line length from 0.15 to a lot bigger it looked just fine. So not an issue with the code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

//show the downsampled point cloud with normals

int vp1 = 0;

viewer->createViewPort(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, vp1); //set viewport to full screen
viewer->setBackgroundColor(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, vp2);  //sets the background to light gray

**viewer->addPointCloudNormals<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::Normal>(downsampled_cloudxyzrgb_ptr, cloud_normals_ptr, 1, 0.1, "Downsampled Point Cloud With Normals", vp1);**

viewer->addCoordinateSystem(10.0, "Downsampled Point Cloud With Normals", vp1);

viewer->createViewPortCamera(vp1);

***Where definitions are:***

pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB::Ptr **downsampled_cloudxyzrgb_ptr** (new pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB);

pcl::PointCloudpcl::Normal::Ptr **cloud_normals_ptr**(new pcl::PointCloudpcl::Normal);

**For background and code on estimating the normals, see:**
https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/normal_estimation_using_integral_images.html

and

https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/normal_estimation.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The supporting documentation links are included in the OP.